# TP-Link WN-772N does not work under Linux

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I am totally new in Linux environment so sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am engineer and I want to try CAELinux which base on xubuntu 12.04. I have installed it and everything works fine apart from my WiFi connection. I have TP-Link WN-772N USB network card and I cannot find any solution for my problem. In one site someone told me to write a few command in terminal and put the results on the site, but no one can help me.

***EDIT****
Unfortunately I do not have keyboard with FN button. I added dmesg|grep ath and used [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://www.pastebin.ubuntu.com).

[results](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9413379/)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: dmesg | grep ath Thanks.

Comment: I have TP link wn722n now with me. on ubuntu I just connect it and start wifi with hardware switch. for me i press Fn+F2 to start wifi

Comment: it will be better if you use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ to give your command line output

Answer (score 0):

In your paste, we see:

> ath9k_htc: Unable to allocate URBs

It is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1088809 The fix is a later kernel version than 3.2.0-xx. I suggest you install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which uses 3.13.0-xx.

Comment: But is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my CAELinux in that way it works properly?

Comment: I have no knowledge of CAELinux. I suggest you search for a later kernel version, at least 3.8, and install it on your current CAELinux system.